# Why their is no badge assigned for profile views

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, views

We already have badges for posting questions or answers, posting chat messages, reviewing,  etc.

Likewise, some badges can be given when profile views exceed 500/1000/10K etc.

Comment: Why should there be such a badge? Why would be want to promote profile views? How is that helping with producing a library of great questions and answers?

Comment: As i said in the question its only a suggestion, it will help the persons with high reputation to became fame

Comment: And how does that help with the ultimate goal of producing a library of great questions and answers?

Comment: That would only lead to a lot profile pictures of naked girls to attract profile views.

Comment: each one trying to maintain a good profile with quality questions and answers. increasing the library size is not a matter, the real fact is to provide good quality questions and answers

Comment: @ juergen : we have flag option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Badge is given for doing something helpful, that contribute to the site either directly (e.g. Nice/Good/Great Question) or indirectly. (e.g. Informed, teaching you how to use the site properly)

When someone see your profile, the site itself gains nothing by it. So, can't see any reason to have such a badge. If you can think of something I missed, feel free to edit your question or comment.

Comment: users are the asset of this site, without then no more questions and no more answer, so i think my suggestion is not wrong.

Comment: @Sujith what makes Stack Exchange different and special is its focus on contents (Questions and Answers) and not on the users.

Comment: the moderators are focused on content, then why the 60% of questions and answers are remains neutral(zero rated), hope that you will do something better. but it will not lead them to rate the question for badge or reputation. thanks for the response